# Alpha Vantage API Define Proxy Python

Tags: python, proxy, alpha-vantage

I am using Alpha Vantage API and python. I was able to successfully install alpha vantage on my machine. Unfortunately I am working in a corporate environment where I have to define a proxy. So this line of code works perfectly fine for me:

```
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimesSeries
```

But this line of code doesn't work:

```
data, meta_data = ts.get_intraday('GOOGL')
```

Last error message from error log is:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
```

I think I have to define the proxy (with credentials) but I don't know where and how for Alpha Vantage API.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify proxies using

```
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://user:pass@10.10.1.0:3128',
    'https': 'http://user:pass@10.10.1.0:3128',
}

ts = TimeSeries(key='your_key')

ts.set_proxy(proxies)
```